# Identify jar file for loaded class in Websphere liberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jersey-2.0

I am getting the following error for a jersey 2 based application running on websphere liberty.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/validation/Configuration.getBootstrapConfiguration()Ljavax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration;
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getTraversableResolver(ValidationBinder.java:287)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getDefaultValidatorContext(ValidationBinder.java:268)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getDefaultValidator(ValidationBinder.java:248)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:199)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:96)

The same application is able to run on websphere full profile. Is there a way to identify the jar file that is being used to load javax.validation.Configuration class. My ear has validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar and there is no other jar in my ear that has javax.validation package.

Comment: What features are you using in `server.xml`? Liberty contains bean-validation-1.0 feature, which is enabled with some other features (like jpa or jsf). You may need to override that with your library see [Overriding a provided API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-2-5-5&lang=en)

Comment: bean-validation-1.0 is implicit added because of servlet-3.0 feature. I moved over to liberty beta and that fixed this problem. Using servlet-3.1 adds bean-validation-1.1 feature. I could not override the provided api with liberty 8.5 as I am using parent first as classloader configuration.